# State reset Issue after Logout React | Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, redux-toolkit

It's a simple app with authorisation `Firebase`, data storage with `Firestore`, `React`, `Redux Toolkit`.

When a user logs out, I need to reset all the data. I do this with `dispatch(removeData())`, `dispatch(removeUserData())`. The states are reset, but immediately the functions are re-run and the data fills the state again, even though `user == null`. When page reload, the state is empty and there is no user.

How can I make it so that when the account is logged out, the state is reset and no more functions are executed?

I've tried many options using `if user !== null`, but none of them work.

If you need any more information I'll edit the question and add it.

**Fetch code**

```
 const memoizedFetchEmails = useMemo(() => {
    async function fetchEmails() {
       ...
    }
    return fetchEmails;
  }, [user]);

  const memoizedFetchSubs = useMemo(() => {
    async function fetchSubs() {
       ...
    }
    return fetchSubs;
  }, [user]);

  const memoizedFetchUserData = useMemo(() => {
    async function fetchUserData() {
      ...
    }
    return fetchUserData;
  }, [user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user !== null) {
      console.log(user?.uid)
      memoizedFetchEmails();
      memoizedFetchSubs();
      memoizedFetchUserData();
    }
  }, [user]);
```

**Actions**

```
removeData(state) {
  state.emails = [];
  state.subs = [];
},

removeUserData(state) {
  state.user = null;
  state.noUser = true;
  state.themeDark = false;
  state.userData = null;
},
```

**Logout function**

```
const logout = () => {
    signOut(auth);
    dispatch(setUser(null))
    dispatch(removeData());
    dispatch(removeUserData());
    navigate("/");
  };
```

[image: Redux Devtools screen]

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      if (currentUser) {
        dispatch(setUser(currentUser));
      } else {
        dispatch(setUser(null));
      }
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: `dispatch(setUser(null));` - Why not set/reset all the state you need to when ***this*** action is dispatched? Please [edit] to include a ***complete*** [mcve] of all the relevant code you are working with that has an issue.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the documentation it seems that the [`signOut` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#signout) is asynchronous, meaning you need to wait for it to complete.

```
const logout = async () => {
  await signOut(auth); // 
  dispatch(setUser(null))
  dispatch(removeData());
  dispatch(removeUserData());
  navigate("/");
};
```

Alternatively you can use an auth state listener to respond to al auth state changes reactively, as shown in the first code sample in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). This approach ensure that your app also handles cases where the sign-in/sign-out isn't handled by an explicit API call in your code, such as when the server can't mint a new token for the user (e.g. because their account is disabled).

Comment: I also used the async method and the result was still the same. Also I use onAuthStateChanged (I added above).

Comment: The main difference is not in marking the function as `async`, but in using `await` on `signOut(auth)`.